# no padding bottom on oveflow scroll

Tags: html, css

itry to get a div that can be scrolled,
i try to add padding but its look like padding bottom didnt work.
how to add padding bottom?

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.scroll {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: red;
  padding: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus modi voluptates vitae! Minus possimus, autem error debitis vel numquam ab incidunt sunt doloremque odit ratione deleniti est ipsa facere, dolorum inventore, ullam labore sint obcaecati
      quasi, nemo. Fuga est minima nihil itaque dolorum omnis consequatur dignissimos, qui id rem, accusantium reiciendis inventore obcaecati ut dolores consectetur nisi non esse facilis? Tempora, perferendis, nostrum! Ex dolor temporibus, laborum facilis
      consectetur ipsam, nostrum, consequuntur atque earum qui officiis in. Eius delectus asperiores veritatis accusamus qui dolore illo expedita veniam tenetur unde voluptatibus deleniti facilis praesentium sapiente iure hic omnis laborum libero quis,
      quibusdam earum quod, consectetur nemo! Ea hic accusantium quidem facere ipsa, non tempore nobis architecto veniam dicta minima aut quasi temporibus fugiat dolorem, deserunt! Officiis, consectetur. Laudantium, vero, ducimus consectetur architecto
      omnis ipsum rerum placeat vitae ea ex autem praesentium. Officia delectus, minima fuga iusto perspiciatis enim molestias ea aliquam omnis saepe, nostrum nulla dolores et dolore nesciunt possimus. Impedit iste, est rerum! Magnam dignissimos aut quos
      necessitatibus, inventore consequuntur pariatur labore, nostrum assumenda dolorem vel in. Consequuntur eaque sed dolorum repudiandae excepturi cupiditate, quod quisquam ea doloribus, molestiae repellat obcaecati hic, qui est nam natus assumenda
      officia enim. Aliquam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uazp78x6/1/

Comment: Where are you trying to add the padding, if it is to the bottom of scrollable area, you are doing it.

Comment: thank you for reply, as you can see in this link https://jsfiddle.net/uazp78x6/2/ the padding bottom didnt work, and as soon as i scroll my padding top is gone. i try to make the top and bottom still have some space from the parent class even when scrolling

Comment: so you want it to have padding on the top and bottom and the innards scroll while having the scrollbar on the outside of the div?

Comment: yappp i try to make like that

Answer (score 0):

Add scroll2 update scroll

```
.scroll2{
  width:150px; 
  height:300px;
  padding-top:20px;
  background:red;
  padding:22px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.scroll{
  width:150px;
  height:260px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:red;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin-left:17px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

}
```

wrap in scroll2 div

```
<div class="scroll2">
    <div class="scroll">
       <div class="content">
        Ipsum...
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you may need to use a plugin to hide scrollbar while making it functional, but it essentially does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to show anytime a *padding alike* at the bottom, then you might need an extra wrapper to lay a mask at the bottom of the box to hide partially the text.

Not too sure that will go along fine with restyling the scrollbar.

example of the idea

```css
  body {
  background: black;
}

.scroll {
  width: 194px;
  height: 344px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scroll:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 1.2em;
  height: 22px;
  top: 305px;
  background: red;
}

.scroll .buffer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 22px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

  p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 22px;
  }
.content {
  padding-bottom: 22px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /*optional: just make scrollbar invisible;$/
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ff0000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="buffer">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus modi voluptates vitae! Minus possimus, autem error debitis vel numquam ab incidunt sunt doloremque odit ratione deleniti est ipsa facere, dolorum inventore, ullam labore sint obcaecati
        quasi, nemo. Fuga est minima nihil itaque dolorum omnis consequatur dignissimos, qui id rem, accusantium reiciendis inventore obcaecati ut dolores consectetur nisi non esse facilis? Tempora, perferendis, nostrum! Ex dolor temporibus, laborum facilis
        consectetur ipsam, nostrum, consequuntur atque earum qui officiis in. Eius delectus asperiores veritatis accusamus qui dolore illo expedita veniam tenetur unde voluptatibus deleniti facilis praesentium sapiente iure hic omnis laborum libero quis,
        quibusdam earum quod, consectetur nemo! Ea hic accusantium quidem facere ipsa, non tempore nobis architecto veniam dicta minima aut quasi temporibus fugiat dolorem, deserunt! Officiis, consectetur. Laudantium, vero, ducimus consectetur architecto
        omnis ipsum rerum placeat vitae ea ex autem praesentium. Officia delectus, minima fuga iusto perspiciatis enim molestias ea aliquam omnis saepe, nostrum nulla dolores et dolore nesciunt possimus. Impedit iste, est rerum! Magnam dignissimos aut
        quos necessitatibus, inventore consequuntur pariatur labore, nostrum assumenda dolorem vel in. Consequuntur eaque sed dolorum repudiandae excepturi cupiditate, quod quisquam ea doloribus, molestiae repellat obcaecati hic, qui est nam natus assumenda
        officia enim. Aliquam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```